# Hibernate Search complains about entity even if it is not indexed at all

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, jpa-2.0, hibernate-search

I've recentlly added Hibernate Search to an existing project with existing entity classes and marked a few entities and fields with Indexed/Field.

However I get following exception at bootstrap time:

```
org.hibernate.search.SearchException: HSEARCH000135: Unable to guess FieldBridge for <some entity class which is not marked with @Indexed>
```

The class which is mentioned changes from time to time, but it is not a class which is marked with @Indexed nor it is related with an entity which is indexed.

Why does it even look at these classes?

I'm using Hibernate 4.2.8 with JPA2 and Hibernate Search 4.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the entity in question has a composite ID, it is probably caused by [this bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HSEARCH-1447).

Comment: Yes it has a composite ID! Is there any workaround except not using a composite ID?

Comment: I don't know any. You can try asking in the bug report.